# gulp-angular-templatecache - combine multiple html partials

Tags: angularjs, gulp

I've three html partials in my application and i'm creating an angular module using gulp template cache.

Html file names:

1. dropdown.html
2. dropdown-select.html
3. dropdown-multiselect.html

Gulp Task:

```
gulp.task('dropdown', function( )
    {
        return gulp.src('modules/dropdown/*.html')
            .pipe(plugins.plumber())
            .pipe(plugins.templatecache({
                output: 'dropdown_template.js',
                moduleName: 'dropdown',
                prepend: 'dropdown.html', // Need to replace with actual file name's
                strip: 'views/'
            }))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('build/js/templates'));
    });
```

After executing the above gulp task. It generates below angular module

```
angular.module("dropdown").run(['$templateCache', function(a) { a.put('dropdown.html', '<div class="dropdown" ng-transclude="parent"></div>\n' +
    ''); // 1st html
    a.put('dropdown.html', '<div ng-transclude="1"></div>\n' +
    ''); //2nd html - name is wrong it should be dropdown-select.html
    a.put('dropdown.html', '<div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu--{{ position }}">\n' +
    '');// 3rd html - name is wrong it should be dropdown-multiselect.html
     }]);
```

a.put('**dropdown.html**') is being generated for all 3 html's. But i need the actual file name instead of dropdown.html. Like below

```
angular.module("dropdown").run(['$templateCache', function(a) { a.put('dropdown.html', '<div class="dropdown" ng-transclude="parent"></div>\n' +
    '');
    a.put('dropdown-select.html', '<div ng-transclude="1"></div>\n' +
    '');
    a.put('dropdown-multiselect.html', '<div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu--{{ position }}">\n' +
    '');
     }]);
```

Please let me know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Strange, it works fine for me. You are using options that I don't see in the [doc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-angular-templatecache). Here is my task:

```
gulp.task('build-templatecache', function() {
    return gulp.src(config.srcPartials)
    .pipe(renameRegex(/\/partials/, ''))
    .pipe(templatecache({
        root: 'partials',
        module: 'game',
        }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(config.destPartials));
});
```